# List Azure AD using UsernamePasswordCredential provider

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using UsernamePasswordCredential provider to connect to AAD and get de users using msgraph-sdk-java (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java), the code is the following:

```
            final UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("client_id")
                .username("user_name")                             
                .password("password")
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"), usernamePasswordCredential);

        final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
          GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
            .buildClient();

        UserCollectionPage userCollectionpage = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();
```

and I am receiving the following error:

> java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password

any idea if I need configure somethings in azure active directory?

Comment: Has the user enabled MFA?

Comment: MFA is disable for the user

Comment: Your code looks fine. But  if you only need to [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java) in Azure AD, you can try the client credential flow . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#ClientCredentialsProvider

Comment: In addition, by the way, the `username/password flow` does not support personal accounts. Not supported even if the personal account is invited to Azure AD tenant. To use this flow, you must use a tenant-specific endpoint `(https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name})`.  Moreover, for security reasons, it is not recommended to use this flow.

Comment: If your account is a guest account, you can try the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#AuthCodeProvider). However, if the guest account wants to list all users, he needs to be an administrator.

Comment: yes the client credential flow is working to list users, but actually what I'm trying to do is authenticate a specific user (with user and password) of my web application against AAD. I found a way to do it using PublicClientApplication and acquiring a token with a username, password and scope. all this using the msal4j library

Comment: 1. Make sure your account is not a personal account. 2. Make sure you enable `Allow public client flows`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtdk.png

Comment: Is there an update? Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Thanks Carl, yes my problem has been solved, using msal4j library and PublicClientApplication class to acquire a token and enabling "Allow public client flow"

Comment: Great! I will summarize our discussion in the answer so that it can help more people, you can mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has been resolved through comments.  Post it as an answer to end the thread:

1. Make sure your account is not a personal account.
2. Make sure you enable `Allow public client flows`.

[image]

3. Using msal4j library and PublicClientApplication class to acquire a token with a username, password and scope.

Comment: 3. Using msal4j library and PublicClientApplication class to acquire a token with a username, password and scope.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I have added it to the answer.