# Unable to read secret from Azure Key Vault Using Username & Password or Enviroment Variables With Java

Tags: java, azure

I have no issue running the code below using Azure CLI just by running az login

```
/**
 * The default credential first checks environment variables for configuration.
 * If environment configuration is incomplete, it will try managed identity.
 */
public void createDefaultAzureCredential() {
    DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();

    // Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
    SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl("https://{YOUR_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net")
        .credential(defaultCredential)
        .buildClient();
}
```

But when I set the code to environment variable like this
[image]

I will encounter this

```
com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables
 are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/az
sdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
```

I know where to find azure_tenant_id but where do I create the AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET?

I also try this code

```
UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1e60e93e1ccf")
            .username("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .password("xxxxxxxxxxx")
            .build();

        // Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
        SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
            .vaultUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net")
            .credential(usernamePasswordCredential)
            .buildClient();
```

And I got this error

```
com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password. To mitigate th
is issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/usernamepasswordcreden
tial/troubleshoot
        at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$authenticateWithUsernamePassword$30(IdentityClient.java
:582)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3811)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:94)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Suppressed: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and pass
word. To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/us
ernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot
                ... 11 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the followi
ng parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: 4957ee5b-ea2d-4e84-8492-10e2efdb4900 Correlation ID: fe1995
94-35eb-4c3e-9b2e-85e38f108f68 Timestamp: 2023-11-01 07:56:17Z
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:
45)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequ
estExecutor.java:161)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:40)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase
.java:256)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGr
antSupplier.java:63)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
                ... 1 more
        Suppressed: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and pass
word. To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/us
ernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot
                ... 11 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the followi
ng parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: a2eba876-aa5c-4b10-8316-9bb8fdc24d00 Correlation ID: 1b8562
10-db80-4b30-85eb-4de206992171 Timestamp: 2023-11-01 07:56:19Z
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:
45)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequ
estExecutor.java:161)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:40)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase
.java:256)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGr
antSupplier.java:63)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
                ... 1 more
        Suppressed: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and pass
word. To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/us
ernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot
                ... 11 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the followi
ng parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: 60dc7021-d436-4a5f-9499-4729bb732500 Correlation ID: 8fca47
e8-07c8-44d4-a2eb-f4fb6670d281 Timestamp: 2023-11-01 07:56:22Z
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:
45)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequ
estExecutor.java:161)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:40)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase
.java:256)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGr
antSupplier.java:63)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69)
                at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
                ... 1 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:100)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1742)
                at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecretWithResponse(SecretClient.java:171)
                at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecret(SecretClient.java:150)
                at com.blobs.quickstart.appupload.main(appupload.java:97)
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following param
eter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: 2d91e058-2470-4f25-ba8e-3eac892d8300 Correlation ID: b5cf0277-fdea-
438b-8388-f6a8184d2492 Timestamp: 2023-11-01 07:56:26Z
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:45)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequestExecu
tor.java:161)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:40)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:25
6)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSuppl
ier.java:63)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
        ... 1 more
```

Please do share your insights?

Answer (score 0):

> com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password. To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/usernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot

The problem is that your application doesn't enable  **`Allow public client flows`**.

Make sure you are MFA is disabled for users and Make sure your account is not a personal account.

Now after enabling  **`Allow public client flows`** in my environment, I tried with the same code, which shows me a secret value.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("xxxx")
            .username("xxxx")
            .password("xxxx")
            .build();

        // Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
        SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
            .vaultUrl("https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net/")
            .credential(usernamePasswordCredential)
            .buildClient();
        String secretName="<My secret name>";
     KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = client.getSecret(secretName);
     System.out.println(retrievedSecret.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
   The secret value is: scjsauicusxxxxx
```

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Register a client application in Microsoft Entra ID for the Azure Health Data Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application#authentication-setting-confidential-vs-public)
2. [List Azure AD using UsernamePasswordCredential provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988712/list-azure-ad-using-usernamepasswordcredential-provider) by Carl Zhao.